# Вернуть true если скобки совпадают

Tags: javascript

Помогите с примером: необходимо вернуть `true` если скобки совпадают, или `false` если нет. Набор скобок такой: `()[]{}`

Например

```
text with([brackets]) true 
text with ([wrong brackets)] false
```

Comment: Что Вы уже делали? Покажите свой код

Comment: Что значит "совпадают"?

Comment: Нет не делал, просто видел такой вопрос на одном из тестов для JS-разработчиков. Если бы был код, то конечно опубликовал, его нет.

Comment: решается с помощью структуры "стек" за O(n).... http://ideone.com/VTB1QI вот пример на паскале (старые добрые школьные времена).

Comment: @pavel, _Runtime error 2 at $0804821D
  $0804821D_ что-то не так? а, это по умолчанию stdin пустой

Comment: вот на С++ код чуть читабельнее думаю http://ideone.com/89lW8h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```js
/**
 * Проверяем корректный порядок скобок в строке
 *
 * @param {String} exp Строка с скобками для проверки
 *
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
function test(exp){
  // Если передали не строку - выходим
  if(typeof exp !== 'string')
    return false;

  let stack = [],
      // Сюда можно добавлять свои скобки: ключ - открываемая, значение - закрываемая
      brackets = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']'},
      openRegExp = [],
      closeRegExp = [],
      str = exp;
  
  // Создаём регулярные выражения для поиска
  Object.keys(brackets).forEach(e => openRegExp.push(`\\${e}`));
  openRegExp = new RegExp(openRegExp.join('|'));
  for(let i in brackets) if(brackets.hasOwnProperty(i)) closeRegExp.push(`\\${brackets[i]}`);
  closeRegExp = new RegExp(closeRegExp.join('|'));
  
  // Добавляем все найденные открывающие скобки в стёк
  while((tmp = openRegExp.exec(str)) && (str = str.substr(++tmp.index))) stack.push(tmp[0]);
  
  str = exp;

  // Если нашли какую-то закрывающую скобку
  while((tmp = closeRegExp.exec(str)) && (str = str.substr(++tmp.index)))
    // То проверяем: Или закончился стёк, а закрывающие скобки всё прибывают
    // Или является ли найденная скобка парой к открывающей скобке в конце стёка (самой глубокой)
    if(!stack.length || brackets[stack.pop()] !== tmp[0]) return false;
  
  // Всё ОК
  return true;
}


[
  `text with([brackets]) true`,
  `text with ([wrong brackets)] false`,
  `()[]{}()sdgsdg(sdg((((sg))))))(([[{sds}]]))`
].forEach(t => console.info(t, test(t)));
```

Comment: Other, спасибо ))

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov, пожалуйста!

Comment: @Other, зачем вам регулярные выражения? Задача решается через стек в один проход строки.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, для наглядности.

Comment: @Other, и вы действительно считаете, что ваш ответ с регулярными выражениями нагляднее моего, без них? =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, у Вас прекрасный ответ, я писал сильно уставший морально, вот и почему-то упустил неиболее очевидный перебор символов как сделали Вы, а написал... это. Хотя разнообразие, наглядно вроде, да и перебор всех символов может быть не так уж хорош на Больших входных строках (регулярки перебирают на плюсах (или на чём там реализация движка), а "вручную" всегда куда дороже). На деле, правда не проверял.

Answer (score 14):

Несмотря на то, что ответ уже дан (и помечен как правильный) существует намного более простой и эффективный (с точки зрения вычислительных ресурсов) способ решения задачи.

(Это особенно важно, если речь идет о собеседовании.)

Суть его заключается в обходе строки и поиске "несбалансированных" скобок с использованием стека. Алгоритм имеет вид:

1. Выбираем первый символ строки
2. Если это открывающая скобка - помещаем ее в стек
3. Если это закрывающая скобка, извлекаем последнее значение из стека и проверяем скобки на соответствие. Если стек пуст или закрывающая скобка не соответствует открывающей - прерываем выполнение и возвращаем `false`
4. Переходим к следующему символу строки и повторяем действия с п.2
5. Если по окончании выполнения алгоритма стек не пуст (это возможно, если открывающих скобок больше, чем закрывающих) - возвращаем `false`.

Реализация на JavaScript может иметь вид:

```
var test = function(str) {
    var chars = str.split(''),
        stack = [],
        open = ['{', '(', '['],
        close = ['}', ')', ']'],
        closeIndex,
        openIndex;

    // Проходимся по строке, проверяя каждый ее символ (п.4).
    for (var i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++) {
       openIndex = open.indexOf(chars[i]);
       if (openIndex !== -1) {
           // Нашли открывающую скобку. Помещаем ее в стек (п.2).
           stack.push(openIndex);
           continue;
       }

       closeIndex = close.indexOf(chars[i]);
       if (closeIndex !== -1) {
           // Нашли закрывающую скобку. Проверяем ее соответствие открывающей (п.3).
           openIndex = stack.pop();
           if (closeIndex !== openIndex) {
               return false;
           }
       }
    }

    // Проверяем дисбаланс открытых/закрытых скобок (п.5).
    if (stack.length !== 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Проверить этот код можно вот на таких примерах:

```
console.log(test('text with([brackets])')); // true
console.log(test('text with ([wrong brackets)]')); // false
console.log(test('text with [wrong brackets')); // false
```

А вот и рабочий пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbkfdjp3/).

Comment: спасибо, очень полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал сам, вот что получилось:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#input'),
    output = document.querySelector('#output');

input.addEventListener('keydown', update);
input.addEventListener('keyup', update);
input.addEventListener('change', update);

function update () {
    var errorMessage;
    
    try {
        balanced.matches({source: input.value, open: ['{', '(', '['], close: ['}', ')', ']'], balance: true, exceptions: true});
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage = error.message;
    }
    
    input.style.border = '10px solid ' + (errorMessage ? 'red' : 'green');
    output.innerHTML = errorMessage || '';
}
update();
```

```css
body {
    background: #333;
    font-family: arial;
}
#input {
    outline: none;
}
#output {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/icodeforlove/node-balanced/master/dist/balanced-min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input" cols="75" rows="10">((([])))</textarea>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: вы думаете что обфусцированный код `https://rawgit.com/icodeforlove/node-balanced/master/dist/balanced-min.js` это то что поможет кому-то ещё решить задачу?

Comment: Нет, но есть живой пример...дальше по пути изучения...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validBraces(braces){
  braces = braces.replace(/[a-zа-яё0-9]/gi, '')
  while(/\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g.test(braces)){braces = braces.replace(/\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g,"")}
  return !braces.length;
 }
```

Пробегаем циклом while по строке пока вхождения в соответствии с регулярным выражением не закончатся, на каждом цикле с помощью replace заменяем найденные вхождения на пустую строку. Возвращаем длину того что осталось в булевом виде.

Comment: в текущем виде это не будет работать на строках указанных в вопросе

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Добавил регулярное выражение вырезающее всё кроме скобок. Проверил на строках в вопросе все работает корректно.

Answer (score -1):

Два варианта решения. Но думаю должно быть более элегантное решение.

Вариант с рекурсией:

```
function verify(string, i = 0, filtered = []) {
  var rules = { '[': ']', '(': ')', '<': '>' };

  if (~Object.keys(rules).indexOf(string[i])) {
    filtered.push(string[i]);
  }

  if (~Object.values(rules).indexOf(string[i])) {
    if (rules[filtered[filtered.length - 1]] !== string[i]) {
      return false;
    }

    if (rules[filtered[filtered.length - 1]] === string[i]) {
      filtered.length = --filtered.length;
    }
  }

  return i !== string.length ? verify(string, ++i, filtered): true;
}
```

Вариант с циклом:

```
function verify(string) {
  var rules = { '[': ']', '(': ')', '<': '>' };

  var result = string.split('').reduce(function (acc, curr) {

  if (~Object.keys(rules).indexOf(curr)) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }

  if (~Object.values(rules).indexOf(curr) && rules[acc[acc.length - 1]] === curr) {
    acc.length = --acc.length;
  }

  return acc;
  }, []);

  return !Boolean(result.length);
}
```